# create textfile -> excape characters individually necessary?

Tags: shell

i need to create textfiles with content like this via shell command:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
   "imageName" : "docker.registry.url.com/username/yourimage:yournewtag"
}
```

so the ideal way for me would be just do

```
touch testfile > {
  "schemaVersion": 2,
   "imageName" : "docker.registry.url.com/username/yourimage:yournewtag"
}
```

how would i be able to do this? do i need to escape every single character? (how would i do this?) or is there any easier way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

answer to myself:

```
echo "{"schemaVersion": 2,"imageName" : "docker.registry.url.com/username/yourimage:yournewtag"}" | tee dockertest
```